# Android : access to thread from another activity

Tags: android, multithreading

I use this code for create 3 thread

After i go to from `MainActivity` to `PageActivity` , how can access to thread `name2`

> MainActivity.java

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            go = true;
            int j = 0;
            while (go) {
                Log.i("Number", j);
                j++;
                if (j == 100) {
                    go = false;
                }
            }
        }

    });
    thread.setName("Name: " + i);
    thread.start();
}
```

Above code runnable

I go to `PageActivity`

I want use `Name2` thread and content of this

How I can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the right way to achieve this would be to implement a [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) that contains your thread (see example [here](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)).

You can [bind the service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) to your activity and access on it's interface with different approaches: extending [Binder class](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder), using a Messenger or implementing an AIDL.